# Can google maps be used on public websites?

Tags: google-maps

Can I use Google maps on public websites?

Are there any licensing / copyright issues?

Comment: yes u can provided you dont remove copyright and google logo at botttom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Google Maps Terms of Service](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) (see especially Sections 9 and 10), you can use Google Maps on a public web site. The biggest requirements are that the application is publicly available for free, and that you include the Google Maps logo on the map.

From Section 9:

> 9.1.1 General Rules.
>
> (a) Free Access (No Fees). Your Maps API Implementation must be
>   generally accessible to users without charge and must not require a
>   fee-based subscription or other fee-based restricted access. This rule
>   applies to Your Content and any other content in your Maps API
>   Implementation, whether Your Content or the other content is in
>   existence now or is added later.
>
> (b) Public Access (No Firewall). Your Maps API implementation must not
>   (i) operate only behind a firewall; or (ii) only on an internal
>   network (except during the development and testing phase); or (iii) in
>   a closed community (for example, through invitation-only access).

From section 9.4:

> 9.4 Attribution.
>
> (b) You agree to include and display the "powered by Google"
>   attribution (and/or any other attribution(s) required by Google as
>   described in the Maps APIs Documentation) conspicuously on the page,
>   in close proximity and adjacent to the Service search box and Google
>   search results. If you use the standard Google search control, or the
>   standard Google search control form, this attribution will be included
>   automatically, and you agree not to modify or obscure this
>   automatically-generated attribution.

Obviously, you and your attorney need to look over the rest of the terms as well to determine if you're willing to accept them.

Answer (score 0):

Review Google's TOS:

- http://www.google.com/help/terms_maps.html
- http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html

(You didn't specify if you're just using the maps or the UI.)

If you need any additional assistance with understanding these terms, please contact Google or a lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking Terms and Conditions to use Google Map
[here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html).